# Running a script with systemd on shutdown or reboot

Tags: systemd, shutdown, reboot

I've made a script which just empties a folder from its contents and then shutdown the pc.

I was wondering if there is a simpler way of doing that automatically when I shutdown or reboot the pc instead of calling the script from the command line. While searching, I found that I probably want a systemd service, but I don't know how to write one and I couldn't find any tutorials on the internet.

After all I just want to run simple single command

```
rm -rf /my/folder/*
```

Am I looking the right way, or is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

I want the folder to empty before shutdown and not after the next boot.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you are manually creating and managing a temporary directory. If that's the case, check the systemd docs for how it can help with this. See `man tmpfiles.d` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a `cron` table entry with a schedule of `@reboot` to remove and/or recreate the directories in question.

Comment: does @reboot run the script before shutdown or during the next boot?

Comment: It runs at system startup, since shutdown kills the `cron` daemon, it cannot tell the kernel "okey dokey, let me just start one new job.."

Comment: i updated my question. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Centos/RHEL 7 there still is a `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` which uses systemd.  I suspect that the same is true on other Linux distributions.  This will run the `rc.local` scripting at reboot.  There is significant commenting and warnings in the file that you should really use the systemd type of run structure.